# Change branch name of Revision 0 in Mercurial repo

Tags: mercurial, branch

The Mercurial repository has two branches that originate from revision 0. Branch names are 2x and 4x.
Rev. 0 itself belongs to branch 4x.

How can I move Rev. 0 to branch 2x keeping everything else the same?

PS. I assume its is totally possible, since the Rev. 0 does not have any dependencies on previous revisions.
PPS. This situation happend after converting the whole repository from incorrectly organized SVN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change a branch name without also changing the changeset hash (ID). Changing a changeset hash will also require a change to all **descendant** changesets. So it doesn't help that revision 0 doesn't have any ancestor changesets — it's the child changesets that complicate things.

My advice: just leave it as it is. Be sure to read the [recommendations on named branches](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/StandardBranching#What_not_to_do) for some good workflow advices.